# Getting wrong distance with neo4j geospatial queries

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am doing some POC around neo4j. I have added nodes to graph using below queries.

```
CREATE p = (:Location {location: point({latitude: 77.74457111606239, longitude: 12.958174189153517})})
RETURN p

CREATE p = (:Location {location: point({latitude: 77.744577645, longitude: 13.958174189153517})})
RETURN p
```

I am calculating the distance between these 2 nodes using below query.

```
MATCH (l1) where ID(l1) = 0
MATCH (l2) where ID(l2) = 1
RETURN point.distance(l1.location, l2.location) AS distance
```

I am getting output = 111319.54315539512

But when I calculate the distance between same lat long locations using online distance calculators it is 23.71 km or 14.73 miles which looks correct.

Not able to understand what I am missing or doing wrong.

Comment: Strange, I tried it on neo4j 5.5 and it returns the correct distance. Are you sure about your output?

Comment: @CharchitKapoor Yes. I cross checked. I am running neo4j locally.

Comment: Ohh. Are there only these two nodes in your system, also what is the neo4j version.

Comment: neo4j version 5.5.0 and I am using community edition. There are other nodes as well and I am facing same issue with other nodes as well.

Comment: Then it's most likely that the nodes represented by id 0 and 1, are not the ones that you expected them to be.

Comment: Added new data and one identifier field to avoid searching by id field.
<br/>CREATE p = (:Location {location: point({latitude: 76.348756348, longitude: 11.2343345}), locationId: '233'})
RETURN p<br/>CREATE p = (:Location {location: point({latitude: 75.348756348, longitude: 13.2343345}), locationId: '234'})
RETURN p<br/>MATCH (l1:Location{locationId: '233'})
MATCH (l2:Location{locationId: '234'})
RETURN point.distance(l1.location, l2.location) AS distance<br/>
Output = 123898.76012042625
Calculated with online calculator = 124.2 km or 77.2 miles
While it is close but still not exact.

Comment: That depends on the algorithm used internally as well, you won't get an exact match.

Comment: Can you run this and give us the result?  Thanks.  MATCH (l1) where ID(l1) = 0
MATCH (l2) where ID(l2) = 1  RETURN l1.location, l2.location

Comment: point({srid:4326, x:77.74457111606239, y:12.958174189153517})

point({srid:4326, x:77.744577645, y:13.958174189153517})

@jose_bacoy This is the output.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use internal node ids in this way. Internal node ids can be recycled/reused and can make it difficult to make sure you are matching on the nodes you actually want. I would imagine you aren't actually computing distance for the nodes you want. Try returning the lat/lng coordinates as well as the distance to confirm what coordinates you are using:

```
MATCH (l1) where ID(l1) = 0
MATCH (l2) where ID(l2) = 1
RETURN point.distance(l1.location, l2.location) AS distance, l1.location, l2.location
```

Are there other properties you can use to reference the nodes in the `MATCH` clause (name, etc)?

Here's the result I get just computing distance between the two points, units are meters (which is consistent with the results you found online):

```
RETURN point.distance(
  point({latitude: 77.74457111606239, longitude: 12.958174189153517}), 
  point({latitude: 77.744577645, longitude: 13.958174189153517}))
--------------------------------------------------------------------
23629.536412350273
```

Comment: I think that might be the case. Let me check and come back. Also request to have look on above comments where I have also pasted output by filtering on internal node ids.